# QA Wizard checkpoint wrong evaluation when using data source?

Tags: automated-tests, perforce

I'm using [QA Wizard Pro](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/qa-wizard-pro) from Perforce. I've added a checkpoint to my automated test case to verify a textbox contains a certain value, which was calculated by the program.

When I use the hard coded value (here 5.273) the test passes

```
Window("FormMain").EditBox("tbClassC").Checkpoint("Text", "5.273", True, "")
```

When I read the value from a data source (excel file) I get an error

```
Window("FormMain").EditBox("tbClassC").Checkpoint("Text", Cell("ClassC"), True, "")
```

Error:

> Control (tbClassC) Property (Text): The "5.273" expected value does not match the actual value of "5.273".

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ba2CX0N31nU) tutorial on how to use the checkpoint feature.

Any idea what I may do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Since I was using an Excel file as source I had to specificly declare the cell as data type `Text`. This way QA Wizard interpreted the excel value as text and not as a number.

[image: Format Cells]